# python if statement not equal to certain numbers

Tags: python

Is there a way to shorten this `if` statement?

```
if i != 9 or i != 23 or i != 25 or i != 33 or i !=35:
    print(i)
```

Comment: It won't matter much for a few elements, you can use a tuple, list etc.. but if you had a lot of values to check a set will be a lot faster

Comment: Thanks, post the answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and check if *i* is *not* in the set:

```
 invalid_set = {9, 23,25, 33, 35} 
 if  i not in  invalid_set:
     # all good
```

A set lookup if `O(1)` vs `O(n)` with a list, tuple etc..

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
if i not in [9,23,25,33,25]:
    print(i)
```